# How to use ansible role from galaxy with my own parameters?

Tags: ansible, ansible-galaxy

I would like to use a role found on ansible galaxy: [robertdebock.java](https://galaxy.ansible.com/robertdebock/java)

I would like to use this role to install java with the version as parameter. I have tried this in my roles/java/tasks/main.yml file:

```
- name: Install Java
  include_role:
    name: robertdebock.java
  vars:
    java_version: 10
```

Unfortunately, only version 11 is installed, no matter what I provide as parameter for `java_version`.

How is it possible to use an existing Galaxy role with my own parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to use an existing Galaxy role with your own parameters.

But in your case, read the [VALID-COMBINATIONS.md](https://github.com/robertdebock/ansible-role-java/blob/master/VALID-COMBINATIONS.md) documentation.

You probably get the default version for your OS:

https://github.com/robertdebock/ansible-role-java/blob/master/vars/main.yml#L73

```
java_openjdk_package: "{{ _java_openjdk_package[java_type][java_version][ansible_distribution] | default(_java_openjdk_package[java_type][java_version]['default'] | default([])) }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass variables to the role when you use it in your playbook:

```
- name: Install Java
  roles: 
  - { role: robertdebock.java, java_version: 10 }
```

As long as the variables use the same name, they will be pulled in as role variables, in [the proper scope](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-scopes)